# convert month-end, or week-end series to daily series

Tags: python, pandas

Let us say I have a pandas series like this:

```
monthly = 
2017-05-31    403.43
2017-06-30    292.92
2017-07-31    184.62
```

Where the index is of type 'datetime64[ns]'.

I'd want to convert it into a daily series where the value each day is just the same value as the month, i.e.,

```
daily_imputed = 
2017-05-01   403.43
2017-05-02   403.43
2017-05-03   403.43
2017-05-04   403.43
....
2017-07-29   184.62
2017-07-30   184.62
2017-07-31   184.62
```

What'd be a good way to achieve this?

Also let us say I have a bi-weekly series,

```
biweekly = 
2017-06-26    151.6
2017-07-10    204.7
2017-07-24    119.2
```

So now I'd want to also convert it to daily where each biweekly value get's imputed as the daily value:

```
daily_imputed = 
2017-06-13    151.6
2017-06-14    151.6
....
2017-07-23    119.2
2017-07-24    119.2
```

It is the same logic as the monthly to daily just with a 13-day lag from last day.  That is why 2017-06-26 starts at 2017-06-13 in the daily imputed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use resample, only problem is that it your first index wont start at the first day of the first month, but you could reindex

```
df.resample('D').first().bfill()
```

you could reindex like so:

```
import datetime as dt
start = df.index[0]
end = df.index[-1]
d_range = pd.date_range(dt.date(start.year, start.month, 1), end)
df.reindex(d_range).bfill()
```

same process with your bi-weekly df should work.

edit: ***now that I am thinking about it, you could just reindex the entire dataframe with the new date range and backfill / forward fill it without using resample!***